# Para qué sirven las interfaces y el modificador abstract en java?, cuál es la diferencia entre implement y extends?

Tags: java, interfaz

En muchas ocasiones he visto personas que en una clase como la siguiente usan el modificador **abstract**:

```
abstract class someclass{
   //Mas codigo...
}
```

Sé que existen entonces modificadores como: private, protected, public, abstract etc. y que algunas clases tienen el modificador **abstract**, sé que la pregunta puede llegar a ser demasiado amplia, pero lo que más me importa es entender tres cosas:

- Para qué sirve el modificador abstract y en que casos se usa.
- En qué repercute que se use el modificador abstract en una clase y qué se debería tener en cuenta al hacerlo.
- Para qué sirven las interfaces, mas no cómo se usan. Sólo para qué sirven y en qué casos se usan.

Ahora, sé que la palabra extends, puede usarse en una clase para extender de otra clase, esto lo que hará es un override del constructor de la clase en que se usa esta palabra y automaticamente obtendra todas las propiedades y métodos de otra clase, aparte de tener un constructor propio, esto no es nuevo y lo he visto en otros lenguajes de programación como javascript lenguaje en el que se usan clases genéricas, pero me queda la duda también en la palabra **implements**, cuál es realmente la diferencia entre implementar y extender?, y qué cosas se puede implementar y extender?, qué cosas no se puede implementar o extender?, esto me tiene pensando mucho, ya que nunca he usado ni una interfaz ni tampoco el modificador abstract por esas razones.

Lo que realmente mas me interesa a mi es saber un poco mas sobre el modificador abstract, muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstract te permite crear una clase abstracta.  Las clases abstractas no pueden ser instanciadas; es decir, que no se diseñan para que puedas crear un objeto con ellas, sino que sirven como base para otras clases; o sea que sólo pueden ser heredadas (extends) por otras clases.

implements permite que tu clase implemente una interface.  Una interface es como un contrato, el cual obliga a la clase que la implementa a tener los métodos que la interface exige.

Una interfacen contiene la estructura de los métodos que usa, pero no el contenido, el cual debe ser implementado en la clase que implemente dicha interface.

Lee un poco sobre el concepto de polimorfismo.  En Java el polimorfismo se implementa con las interfaces.